# Возврат ошибки file upload yii2

Tags: php, yii2

использую виджет от dos amigos fileuploadUI
https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-file-upload-widget

При успехе вовзаращается в jsone вот такой массив

```
return Json::encode([
                'files' => [
                    [
                        'name' => $model->video->name,
                        'size' => $model->video->size,
                        'url' => $filePath2,
                        'thumbnailUrl' => $filePath2,
                        'deleteUrl' => '/ajax/delete1?name=' . $fileName,
                        'deleteType' => 'POST',
                    ],
                ],
            ]);
```

Однако мне при определенных условиях (при превышении дисковой квоты) надо возвращать false и соответственно выводить ошибку . Как это сделать?

Comment: Ну как - возвращаете пустой массив фалов с доп. описанием ошибки, либо сразу HTTP код, соответствующий ошибке.

Comment: Во всякому пробовал, если вы сталкивались с этим, не могли бы мне помочь?

Comment: Не сталкивался, но ваш код может быть примерно таким - return Json::encode(['files' => [], 'error' => 'Размер файла превышает допустимый в XXX МБ']);

Comment: К сожалению попробовал, не помогает, все равно срабатывает метод fileuploaddone, что означает что якобы все ок. выходит вот такая ошибка. Empty file upload result

Comment: Я вам на yiiframework ответил, сделайте все как надо с валидаторами AR.